# How can I control (start/stop) applications and services that start up after reboot?

Tags: macos, performance, startup, services

I have a Mac that is slow when using the internet, but other PCs on the same connection aren't as slow.

I suspect there are too many AV scanners running concurrently, or there is some process that isn't installed by default slowing the whole thing down.

**Question**

Where can I find **all possible applications** that will be automatically started when the machine turns on?  (and how do I shut them off)

This should include

- Applications on the menu bar on the bottom
- Services (like Antivirus)
- Menu-bar applications

Comment: What do you mean by "too many AV scanners"? It's advised to only use one AV live scanner at a time. However, it's fine to have several on-demand AV scanners.

Comment: I suspect that many AV scanners are working at the same time.  I see Clam AV, and many others.  @gentmatt What singluar scanner is best (paid or non paid)

Comment: I can't say because I've not yet seen any thorough comparison of AV scanners in OSX. I myself use Sophos because it offers live scanning and scheduled scanning of certain parts of the drive - for free.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Applications and Menu Bar items

Most of these can be easily configured in:
*System Preferences → Users&Groups → **Login Items***

### LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons

Some applications are cannot be configured in the *System Preferences* (e.g. Sophos AV Scanner, HandsOff Firewall,...) It's best to configure them in their own application to assure that everything runs as designed and intended.

You can look for related **LaunchAgents** and **LaunchDaemons** in:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents               ~/Library/LaunchDaemons
/Library/LaunchAgents                /Library/LaunchDaemons
/System/Library/LaunchAgents         /System/Library/LaunchDaemons
```

### Startup Items

After I installed the multi-boot utility rEFIt, it copied a file `rEFItBlesser` which is run at startup.
Items that run at startup can be found in the following locations:

```
~/Library/Startup Items
/Library/Startup Items
```

Comment: Basically, this is a great introduction, but the full answer is to learn all of launchd and make sure all the legacy launchers that [launchd replaced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) but that software can bundle and activate like cron, rc.d and such...

Comment: @bmike Yes, I still got a lot to learn :) This is just as much as I can help. If anybody wants to elaborate certain parts, we can make this answer a wiki post.

Comment: I like it. The question is about where do things get started and to a first approximation, launchd and startup items preference pane is the answer. I wouldn't change anything here. I'll consider adding a contrasting answer later - how to test the idea that too much running is the cause of slowness by safe booting or running the OS installer to an external drive and A/B testing. For most, that is much more time-efficient than actually learning the guts of how launchd works. Having both will help more people that have similar issues.

Comment: I found ClamAV in addition to Sophos in ~\Library\LaunchAgents  I uninstalled ClamAV by dragging the application to the trash, but the .pslist file didn't get removed so I manually removed it.  Was this a correct action to take?

Comment: @makerofthings7 That's interesting because I don't have anything related to SophosAV in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. However I do have a file `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.sophos.uiserver.plist`. If you have uninstalled ClamAV there is no problem to remove the `.plist` as well.

Comment: Looking ahead: [App Store apps that comply](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wlo0w.png) with sandboxing guidelines may no longer appear in the Users & Groups pane of System Preferences.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin Do you mean, as 'Login Items`?

Comment: @gentmatt yes (there's *Login Items* in the linked screenshot … although the shot is **not** of System Preferences – sorry for any confusion).

Comment: @gentmatt Thanks for the locations info in the answers but would be nice to know how to remove these applications. Spotify places its thing there -com.spotify.webhelper.plist . Is it ok to just remove it as rm -rf com.spotify.webhelper.plist ?