# Where does mysql register to start itself at boot time?

Tags: macos, startup, launchd, daemons

I've got a Macbook Air that is starting mysql on boot.  I've looked in LaunchAgents, LaunchDaemons, .bash_profile and .profile and login items.  It's also not in /etc/rc.local.

Where else can I look?

Comment: I don't know what mysql is doing lately - have a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66498/how-can-i-control-start-stop-applications-and-services-that-start-up-after-reb in case you get some ideas there.

Answer (score 1):

It's in /Library/StartupItems.